# matlab convert video into Binary and playit back

Tags: arrays, matlab, video-processing

im tryin to test something using matlab but im havin trouble saving frames that i have import it from video and covert it to binary, now i want to save these frames into an array and play it back / sav it to avi

Here is a code example

```
b='1.avi';
vidObj=VideoReader(b);%intialize video object and save info
framerate=floor(vidObj.FrameRate);
totalframes=floor(vidObj.NumberOfFrames);
for i=2:totalframes
vid=read(vidObj,1);%%load frame
ref=rgb2gray(vid); %% convert to gray %% adjust contrast
level=graythresh(ref); %% calculate threshold
vid=im2bw(ref,level); && <<< how can i push this back into array and playit back ?

end
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

See the *movie* and *im2frame* commands [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/movie.html) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/im2frame.html).